# How do you escape pipes '|' when using azure-cli from git bash

Tags: windows, pipe, escaping, git-bash, azure-cli

Ran into a problem when using `azure-cli` in Git Bash

The command:

```sh
az webapp create --name app-name --resource-group rg-name --plan plan-name --runtime "node|10.14"
```

Error:

```sh
'10.14' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

[image: illustration shows error results as seen on Git Bash]

> Update: Found related issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13866

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side?

Comment: nope last i tried only works on Command Prompt. Git Bash and PowerShell fails.

Comment: Could you try Azure cloud shell? Probably, it's a problem with your working environment. Could you uninstall your PowerShell completely then re-install the az.powershell and Az cli command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an odd thing. I tried this command in Bash of Azure Cloud Shell or WSL or Git Bash on my windows 10. All worked fine.

Cloud Shell
[image]

Git Bash
[image]

In this case, you could consider updating your CLI installation with `az upgrade` or re-install your [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) or [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads). Also, you could check if you have the correct character format when typing the `"node|10.14"`.

Comment: many thanks Nancy, not sure what worked, but I noticed the reinstalled Git Bash is slightly different from the older version. All works okay now, cheers!